# How to create a Post request in Fiddler

Tags: http-post, fiddler

trying to send a Fiddler Post request to my C# API as follows *(this is my dev environment using VS2012)*. However, my request object is `null` in C#. In the parsed tab of the composer tab. My post URL: `http://localhost:33218/api/drm`

```
User-Agent: Fiddler/4.4.9.2 (.NET 4.0.30319.34209; WinNT 6.1.7601 SP1; en-US; 4xAMD64)
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Language: en-US
Host: localhost:33218
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 80
```

Request Body:

```
&sid=f7f026d60bb8b51&riskMeasureName=RMTest
```

And here's the C# API method:

```cs
// POST api/drm 
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JObject drmObject)
{
     string sid = drmObject.GetValue("sid").ToString();
     string riskMeasCategory = drmObject.GetValue("riskMeasureName").ToString();
     string response = DynAggrClientAPI.insertDRMCategory(sid, riskMeasCategory);

     var httpResp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     httpResp.Content = new StringContent(response, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

     return httpResp;
}
```

I can debug in my C# `Post()` method, but the `drmObject` is `null`.

Your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not sending a content-type, so MVC has no way to tell how to interpret the data.

Your data seems to resemble a form POST, so add the header:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: wow, I must have removed it. That certainly worked upon adding `Content-Type` ! @CodeCaster